# Change ViewPagerIndicator to Icon, not Text

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm using the following library:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
to set a ViewPagerIndicator(TitlePageIndicator)

```
TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

I have a hardcoded, declared array of   String

```
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "#", "Home", "Icon" };
```

and in my ViewPager Adapter, I simply set the name of the tab like so:

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }
```

This all works fine. My question is- can I change the tab "title" to an *icon* instead of *text*? Is this possible? If not, is there any other tool I should be using to achieve this?

I have looked at the "stock" examples, and I have not seen something like an icon.

As we can see, [Pinterest](http://cultofandroid.cultofmaccom.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/pinterest1.jpg) does this with their main center tab.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the FixedIconTabs example from the ViewPageExtensions project [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Moo.png). Is that what you want ?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Moo.png) - https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

Edit - Adding a pic

[image: Pager with icons]

Comment: I'll look at it in a bit. Hmph, looks like there is no screenshot so I'll have to run the full example project. 

I'll let you know, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the ViewPagerIndicator Library and the Samples project.  There's a sample FragmentActivity called SampleTabsWithIcons that, as you'd guess, uses icons in the tabs (also text, though I'm pretty sure it could use just icons).  Now, you indicated that you're trying to make titles use icons, not tabs, though, so I don't know if this is helpful.  I'm not that familiar with ViewPage, and the difference between titles and tabs is not obvious to me, but if you really need icons for titles, not tabs, then this may not help.  Below is a screenshot from the "Tabs with Icons" screen in the app on my phone.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this, but yes, I'm going for titles and I'm not sure if it's entirely the same thing.

I'll try it out, and let you know.