# Android use pagerindicator with icons

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, title

How do I use icons instead of plain text on my Android ViewPager Indicator tabs? I'm looking for it but I couldn't find nothing about it on the web.

And by the way, is it possible to change the aspects of the page indicator during runtime? How can I achieve that? Thank you very much

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you try this [https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) one of the best `ViewPagerIndicator Library` in Market

Comment: Sorry I should mention that I'm using that library already. I just don't know how to change the text for icons

Comment: Which text, for which icons?

Comment: Try using TabPageIndicator from this library. I've made changes to it to pass icon with the text in each page.

Comment: You can Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833617/change-viewpagerindicator-to-icon-not-text